# The requested URL /dashboard was not found on this server

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp-linux-x64-7.1.31-2. When I try to run `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`, the output is:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.1.31-2...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

However when I navigate to `localhost/dashboard` the browser gives me a 404. I have also tried replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try with the command `sudo service --status-all` to see what web servers are running, because your error says: `Another web server is already running`

Comment: apache2 and mysql have a [+] in front in the output of the above command.

Answer (score 0):

In my user's point of view, you must first run

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

in your issues and then run

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```